# How to set up DSL Internet connection in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, internet

I am having some problems setting up Internet connection in the latest version. When on Windows, I just insert the plug and enter the password and user name provided by my ISP and it would work. But when it comes to Ubuntu, I tried `sudo pppoeconf` several times and **command not found** keeps popping up.

I have also tried `nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name “YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME”` but when I finished the setting, it keeps failing to connect to the Internet even though I did add a new Internet connection option.

After plugging and unplugging the Ethernet cable several times I still can't solve the problem. Has anyone run into the same trouble before? How did you manage to solve it? Thank you

Comment: "I tried sudo pppoeconf several times and command not found keeps popping up." Did you first install it? `sudo apt update && sudo apt install pppoeconf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu 20.10 you can use nm-connection-editor, Give this a try and let me know

From terminal run this command

```
nm-connection-editor -s
```

This should pop a utility using which you should be able to add pppoe or any other type of connection easily.